# Mercurial Merge of Two Named Branches: Working Directory Has No Ancestor

Tags: mercurial

I have two named branches, SPRINT_009 and SPRINT_010.  Some changesets have been committed to SPRINT_009 that I would like to merge into SPRINT_010.  I was able to merge the changesets from branch_one back into default without any trouble.  I am having problems merging the changesets from branch_one into branch_two.

```
default       A -- B -- C -- G -- H -- I -- J -- K -- L -- N -- O -- P
                         \                             \            /
SPRINT_009     D -- E -- F -----------------  ---------- ----------
                                                         \
SPRINT_010                                                M
```

Here are the commands I am using:

```
hg update branch_two
hg merge branch_one
```

However I get the following message:

```
abort: merging with a working directory ancestor has no effect
```

Does anyone know what exactly I am doing wrong?

**EDIT: I've added a picture of the graph.  The drawing is conceptual **
[image]

Comment: As you've drawn it, there should be no problem, so is the drawing accurate?  Is M's only parent L?

Comment: M should only see that message when merging with ABCGHIJK or L (any ancestor of M).

Comment: @MarkTolonen - I've updated the post with an image of the actual graph.

Comment: Assuming `hg update SPRINT_010` and `hg merge SPRINT_009` that should work without error.  In fact merging from any of the branch heads shown to any other branch head should have no error.  What are the exact commands you use as well?

Comment: Also, run `hg ident -ni` after the `hg update`; this will give you the short-form changeset ID and the revision number; see if these are what you would expect to see after running `hg update`

Comment: @MarkTolonen I am trying to merge SPRINT_009 into SPRINT_010.  I execute `hg update SPRINT_010` to update to the SPRINT_010 branch.  I then execute `hg merge SPRINT_009` to merge SPRINT_009 in.

Comment: @smoothreggae After updating to SPRINT_010, `ht ident -ni` shows that I am at the tip of the SPRINT_010 branch.

Comment: Your screenshot suggests that you might be using TortoiseHg; have you tried (a) select "Update" from the context menu at the tip of SPRINT_010 (b) select "Merge with Local" from the context menu at the tip of SPRINT_009 ?

Comment: That message usually means that there are no changeset to merge -- in other words, two heads are identical.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem was that I hadn't performed an `hg pull` before attempting the merge.  Normally we do our development on a Windows machine using TortoiseHg.  We modified the name of one of our resources on the support branch, from fooBAR to fooBar and ran into the [mercurial case folding](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CaseFolding) problem.  We were trying to get around this by merging the branches on a Linux box.  I am so used to using TortoiseHg that I forgot the most basic of commands!